# Google BigQuery Create/append to table from Avro internalError

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, avro

I am fairly new to BigQuery, however I have been able to create and append to existing BigQuery tables from Avro files (both in EU region) until 1-2 days ago. I am only using the web UI so far.

I just attempted to create a new table from a newly generated Avro file and got the same error, details below:

```
Job ID  bquijob_670fd977_15655fb3da1
Start Time  Aug 4, 2016, 3:35:45 PM
End Time    Aug 4, 2016, 3:35:53 PM
Write Preference    Write if empty
```

> Errors:
>   An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.
>   (error code: internalError)

I am unable to debug because there is not really anything to go by.

Comment: Does the job show any more details here? -> https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get

Answer (score 0):

We've just released a new feature to not creating the root field: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/release-notes.

Since you have imported Avro before, we have excluded your project from this new feature. But unfortunately we had a bug with exclusion, and will cause reading Avro to fail. I think you most likely ran into this problem.

The fix will be released next week. If you don't need the root field and want to enable your project for the new feature, please send the project id to me, huazhang at google.com. Sorry for the trouble this has caused.

Comment: Thank you Huazhang. This is all good to know. I think we will request this new feature but wish to confirm with the team first.